# deserializacion json newtonsoft deja el objeto con todo en null C#

Tags: c#, jsonobject

Saludos tengo el siguiente problema resulta que intento deserializar un json con la libreria de newtonsoft con la siguiente linea

Tramite body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Tramite> (JsonBody);

Json que envio:

```
{
   "body":[
      {
         "id":3772,
         "processInstanceId":"1416",
         "tipoTramite":{
            "id":1,
            "descripcion":"Solicitud Patente Comercial (Municipalidad)"
         },
         "canal":{
            "id":0,
            "nombre":""
         },
         "definicionTramite":{
            "id":282,
            "tipoTramite":null,
            "idEstado":0,
            "version":3,
            "idDepartamento":0,
            "idArea":0,
            "nombre":"Solicitud Patente Comercial (Municipalidad)",
            "codigo":null,
            "descripcion":null,
            "deploymentId":null,
            "configuracion":null,
            "processId":null
         },
         "institucion":{
            "id":1045,
            "idInstitucionBase":null,
            "tipoInstitucion":null,
            "nombre":"Municipalidad de La Granja",
            "codigo":"LAGRANJA",
            "direccion":null,
            "logoWeb":null,
            "logoPdf":null,
            "telefonoFijo":null,
            "email":null,
            "propietario":null
         },
         "idDepartamento":1,
         "idArea":3,
         "estado":{
            "id":294,
            "definicionTramite":{
               "id":282,
               "tipoTramite":null,
               "idEstado":0,
               "version":0,
               "idDepartamento":0,
               "idArea":0,
               "nombre":null,
               "codigo":null,
               "descripcion":null,
               "deploymentId":null,
               "configuracion":null,
               "processId":null
            },
            "codigo":"03",
            "nombre":"En Proceso"
         },
         "cve":"3df31748ec86df4280ecfaa853ead07a8918b345",
         "numeroSolicitud":"555",
         "tarifa":0,
         "rut":{
            "numero":13639987,
            "dv":"K"
         },
         "rutEmpresa":{
            "numero":76291578,
            "dv":"2"
         },
         "nombre":"Solicitud Patente Comercial (Municipalidad)",
         "flagPagado":false,
         "fechaCreacion":1508792522683,
         "fechaModificacion":1508792809726,
         "datosTramite":[
            {
               "id":0,
               "key":"inmueble_direccion_numero",
               "tipo":"string",
               "data":"3334"
            }
         ],
         "deploymenId":"cl.corfo.municipiogenerico:bpm-patentegenerica:1.4",
         "processId":"patenteGenerica",
         "solicitante":"FÃ‰LIX EDUARDO CIFUENTES CID",
         "contribuyente":"NombreMock de Fantasia",
         "keyConfiguracion":"patente-comercial-ampliacion-giro"
      }
   ]
}
```

Asi Queda El Objeto
[image: Asi Queda El Objeto:]
Clase que serializo:

```
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string processInstanceId { get; set; }
        Dictionary<string, string> tipoTramite { get; set; }
        Dictionary<string, string> canal { get; set; }
        public DefinicionTramite definicionTramite { get; set; }
        public Institucion institucion { get; set; }
        public int idDepartamento { get; set; }
        public int idArea { get; set; }
        public Estado estado { get; set; }
        public string cve { get; set; }
        public string numeroSolicitud { get; set; }
        public double tarifa { get; set; }
        Dictionary<string, string> rut { get; set; }
        Dictionary<string, string> rutEmpresa { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public bool flagPagado { get; set; }
        public string fechaCreacion { get; set; }
        public string fechaModificacion { get; set; }
        public List<DatosTramite> datosTramite { get; set; }
        public string deploymenId { get; set; }
        public string processId { get; set; }
        public string solicitante { get; set; }
        public string contribuyente { get; set; }
        public string keyConfiguracion { get; set; }
```

Clase Definicion Tramite

```
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string tipoTramite { get; set; }
    public int idEstado { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    public int idDepartamento { get; set; }
    public int idArea { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string deploymentId { get; set; }
    public string configuracion { get; set; }
    public string processId { get; set; }
```

Clase Institucion

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string idInstitucionBase { get; set; }
public string tipoInstitucion { get; set; }
public string nombre { get; set; }
public string codigo { get; set; }
public string direccion { get; set; }
public string logoWeb { get; set; }
public string logoPdf { get; set; }
public string telefonoFijo { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
public string propietario { get; set; }
```

Clase Estado

```
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DefinicionTramite definicionTramite { get; set; }
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
```

Clase Datos Tramite

```
       public int id { get; set; }
       public string key { get; set; }
       public string tipo { get; set; }
       public string data { get; set; }
```

todas estas son las clases que estan involucradas en la deserializacion del json que envio, intenté deserializar a un dataSet pero tampoco podia debido a las clases que contenia (según lo que lei en una pregunta de stackoverflow) si alguien sabe que tengo malo o si hay otra forma de hacer la deserializacion de un json en C# me sirve

Comment: Hola @Nicolas por favor no es una buena practica colocar el código en imágenes. si puedes edita tu pregunta. Gracias

Comment: gracias por la recomendación, ya actualice la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Para que la deserialización de tu JSON funcione necesitas emplear una clase por encima de la clase **Tramite**. En tu JSON no tienes un objeto **Tramite** sino un objeto con una propiedad **body** que es, a su vez, un array de objetos de tipo **Tramite** (en este caso el array sólo tiene un elemeneto).

Puedes emplear una clase como la siguiente:

```
public class RaizTramites
{
    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public List<Tramite> Tramites { get; set; }
}
```

Y la hora de ejecutar la deserialización lo harías así:

```
var raizTramites = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RaizTramites>(JsonBody);
```